# a way to search for strings in real time .txt or .log file for strings

Tags: java, string

I am learning Java programming and I am doing well.

I am working on this project at work. Let me carefully lay out what I need.

My computer is connected to a tool I will call 'A'. This tool streams data to my computer 'B' in real time.

Two logs are created:

- One on the screen that I can clear or save.
- Second one is a A log created in the background.

Is there a way I can query this changing background log which is a copy of the data being streamed for predetermined keywords or strings and output that immediately on the screen? How do I go about this? what's the efficient way? How about listening to the ports.

I just want to accomplish this in real time.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: All I have tried is to make sure I can pull up a saved log. Pretty much just a file read. I am just looking for a way to read the log real time. We are talking about thousands of line. I am just trying to flag key words in real time. So, instead of post processing, I want to implement real time processing. I just don't know how, but I don't want to use already developed one so that i can have the potential to expand it.

Comment: `I just don't know how` is too broad for any one of us to help you since we're not a traditional Q&A site (and we like keeping the questions asked high quality so other people whom may have the same code issue can learn from the problems other people have already solved). I highly recommend you to find or write an example, and ask a targeted question as to what doesn't make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

if this is linux box you can do

```
tail -f <my_log_file_name>| grep <my key word>
```

if you have Windows box try [baretail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) - free (and I think great tool) which color your keyword